# compactly generated spaces, trivial topology.

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space with trivial topology (only $X$ and $\emptyset$ are open). Is $X$ a compactly generated space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subset $K\subseteq X$ is compact. The only closed subsets of $X$ are $X$ itself and $\emptyset$, so if $K\subseteq X$ then $K\cap X=K$ and $K\cap \emptyset = \emptyset$ are (the unique) closed subsets of $K$ (in the subspace topology). Thus the topology of $X$ is compactly generated.

Answer (score 0):

A space with the indiscrete topology is compact.  So the result follows from the more general:

**Proposition:** Any compact space $X$ is compactly generated.

*Proof*: Take a subset $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\cap K$ is closed in $K$ for all compact $K\subseteq X$.  Since $X$ is compact, taking $K=X$ in particular gives that $A$ is closed in $X$.  That is what we needed to show.